# Braintree sandbox account does not show transaction

Tags: paypal, sandbox, braintree

i am android side client token generate and get nonce object to pass my server now php side checkouut file

```
  <?php

require_once(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'config.php');

$nonceFromTheClient = $_POST['payment_method_nonce']
$amount = $_POST['amount']
$merchantAccountId = someFunctionToLookupCorrectMerchantIdBasedOnCurrency();

 $result = Braintree_Transaction::sale([
'amount' => "10.00",
'paymentMethodNonce' => $nonceFromTheClient,
'merchantAccountId' => $merchantAccountId,
'options' => [
    'submitForSettlement' => True
   ]
]);
 $transaction = $result->transaction;
 $transaction->paymentInstrumentType ==    
Braintree_PaymentInstrumentType::PAYPAL_ACCOUNT;
# false
  $transaction->paymentInstrumentType ==    
 Braintree_PaymentInstrumentType::CREDIT_CARD;
```

these my code after the checking sandbox accout transaction does not show transaction summary what i am do please help me advance in thanks

Client side code

```
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get("http://192.168.0.102:8080/btsample/client_token.php", new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String clientToken) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, clientToken.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("clientToken",clientToken.toString());
          //  onBraintreeSubmit("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");
           onBraintreeSubmit(clientToken.toString());
           // onBraintreeSubmit("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");
        }
    });
}

public void onBraintreeSubmit(String Token) {

    PaymentRequest paymentRequest = new PaymentRequest().clientToken(Token);
    startActivityForResult(paymentRequest.getIntent(this), REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            PaymentMethodNonce paymentMethodNonce = data.getParcelableExtra(
                    BraintreePaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT_METHOD_NONCE
            );
            String nonce = paymentMethodNonce.getNonce();
            Log.d("nonce",nonce);
            postNonceToServer(nonce);
        }
    }
}

    void postNonceToServer(String nonce) {
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("payment_method_nonce", nonce);
    params.put("amount", 20);
    client.post("http://192.168.0.102:8080/btsample/checkout.php", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            Log.d("responsebody",responseBody.toString());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, responseBody.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
        }
     }
  );
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

My code is perfect working php server side static amount pass use 'fake-valid-nonce' and client side amount pass  use the 'paymentMethodNonce' => nonceFromTheClient, the code is perfect working

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

There could be a number of reasons your transaction isn't registering in the gateway. You should ensure

1. Your [API credentials](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-server/php#see-also) are all set and available to your server side integration
2. You are [generating a unique client token](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-server/php#send-a-client-token-to-your-client) in your server and sending it to your client
3. You are [generating a paymentMethodNonce](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/android/v2#present-drop-in-ui) in your client and sending it back to your server
4. Use the nonce to create your new transaction.
5. Check the [transaction result object](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/transaction/php#result-object) that is returned from `Braintree_Transaction::Sale` to check for errors.

From what you have posted of your specific implementation, I recommend you double check that `someFunctionToLookupCorrectMerchantIdBasedOnCurrency()` returns a valid merchantID, `$nonceFromTheClient` is defined and unique, and that your client is receiving a client token.

For more help specific to your integration, contact [Braintree support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/).

Comment: does not showing sandbox account transaction summary

Comment: pass the server payment does not show in transaction  i have manuaaly transaction payment succesful show the transaction

Comment: what is the problem this code what i need sandbox crediantia; transaction does not show

Comment: "paymentMethodNonce" => 'fake-valid-nonce'  i have chage the code these working  but nonceobject pass does not working why???